# Pendrive to install Solus Linux doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, bootable, solus

I've downloaded Solus Linux ISO (with the GNOME desktop)  from [its official site](https://solus-project.com/download/). Then, I booted into Windows, opened Rufus, and burned the ISO into my pen drive with the GPT partitioning scheme for UEFI as my HDD's partition table is GPT and I've set the boot mode to UEFI only from the BIOS.

When I boot from my pen drive, I'm presented with a menu with just one option:

> Reboot into firmware interface

which when selected, directs me to the BIOS settings page. I can't see a way to try Solus and install it.

I've downloaded Solus Linux with the BUDGIE window manager as well, but I face the same problem. I can install other OSes just fine.

How can I try and install Solus?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to burn the ISO using DD mode.

I burned it in ISO mode. Hence the problem.

More info at the [installation guide](https://solus-project.com/articles/installation/preparing-to-install/en/)

Comment: so, the problem was not with the installation procedure, but with the creation of the live usb